# Javascript Error | Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error on this line of code:

```
$('.board-list').on('mixEnd', function() {
   $('[style="display: inline-block;"]:nth-child(6n)').css('margin-right': 0);
});
```

My error reads:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Can someone explain where I am missing a closing bracket?

Comment: change to `.css({'margin-right': 0})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `('margin-right': 0);` to `('margin-right', 0);`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldsgdr8g/)

Answer (score 2):

Use Either:-

```
.css({'margin-right': 0});
```

Or

```
.css('margin-right', 0);
```